# get difference between two lists of tuples

Tags: python

```
a=[(1,2),(2,3),(3,5),(4,1)]
b=[(1,3),(2,3),(3,5),(4,3)]
```

I want to compare each element in the list according to their index number, namely the first item to the first item, the second item to the second item, and so on..

if they match, do nothing, it they don't match, append to new list.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: By the way for your question it is pretty irrelevant that you have tuples in your lists.

Comment: Append what to a new list, the element from `a`, the element from `b`, or both?

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for x, y in zip(a, b):
...     if x != y:
...         result.append(x)
...         result.append(y)
... 
>>> result
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (4, 1), (4, 3)]
```

Fun:

```
>>> sum(([x,y] for x,y in zip(a, b) if x != y), [])
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (4, 1), (4, 3)]
```

The general lesson you should learn here is that whenever you want to compare iterables element-wise, use the `zip` builtin. Everything after that is completely straight forward (in the vanilla version).

Answer (score 0):

If the lists are the same length like the example you provided, and you want to append the two elements that don't match you can use:

```
    a=[(1,2),(2,3),(3,5),(4,1)]
    b=[(1,3),(2,3),(3,5),(4,3)]
    c = []
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        if a[i] != b[i]:
            c.append(a[i])
            c.append(b[i])
    print c
```

output:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (4, 1), (4, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a classical `for` loop.

```
l = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] != b[i]:
        l.append(a[i])
        l.append(b[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple list comprehension:

```
a=[(1,2),(2,3),(3,5),(4,1)]
b=[(1,3),(2,3),(3,5),(4,3)]

new_list = [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] != b[i]]
```

Comment: Using `zip` woud be cleaner: `[ai for ai, bi in zip(a, b) if ai != bi]`.